# updating multiple records in php from multiple textbox (textbox name depends on number of records)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table that holds records of grades of student, these students are in a group. some have 5 members some have 4, 3 or 2. The page where grades can be edited returns all the names of the group selected with a textbox corresponding to each of them.

this is the part of my code that returns the said output:

```
<table>
while($data= mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$data['Student Name'].'</td>
<td><input type="text" name="HELP_ME_HERE" value="" /></td>
</tr>';
}
</table>
```

let's say the $query returned 3 records. what I need to happen is that the 3 textboxes that would be echoed out should have different Name like for example it should be named as HELP_ME_HERE1, HELP_ME_HERE2, HELP_ME_HERE3. I need that to happen so I could easily call each values to be used for updating all 3 records in 1 click. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val;
function fun(val)
{
  if(val<50 || val>100)
  {
     alert("You are allowed to enter values 50-100");
     document.getElementById("num").value="";
  }
}    
</script>


     <table>
        <?php 
        $i=1;
        while($data= mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {  ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $data['Student Name']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="HELP_ME_HERE<?php echo $i; ?>" value="" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode>=48 && event.keyCode<=57)|| event.keyCode==8" onchange="fun(this.value)" /></td>
        </tr>
       <?php $i++; }  ?>
      </table>
```

Here i have simply added `php` code in html and a variable is incremented which will make your name as in increment form.

2. In this editing, you can see on change of the value i.e. less than 50 or more than 100, it will give alert box and erase the textbox value. And you can see in `onkeydown`  i have restricted users to press only number keys or backspace if required.

Hope this solves your query.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: yay! it worked :) thanks, but I have a follow up question for this.

I want these textboxes to have its limits (max and min values). I've set it max="100" and min="50" but still the user is able to enter numbers <50 and 100>. what I want to happen is once the user enters 49 and below or 101 and above it shall automatically change the value to 100 (if it exceeds 100) or 50 (if it's below 50). Do you know how to do this?

Comment: if it worked kindly mark it as accepted....and yes i'll also let you know about your other question....

Comment: that you need to do with  `jquery` i'll edit my answer and let you know.

Comment: Here i am editing answer as per your new question, kindly look into it remember if you put max and min you have to restrict to it to enter only numbers....

Comment: ive already done that. only numbers are allowed to be entered (keypress evt) i just need it to be validated upon input not upon submit. .

Comment: got it working now. thanks for that. One last thing :) 

$ii = 1;
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$stud(here) = $_POST['stud'(and here)]; <<<<

$ii++
}

I want to declare variables using the loop you suggested in setting the name on my textboxes. as you can see (here , andhere) I want that to have numbers 1,2,3 or depending the number of records returned by my query. the problem here is that I want to declare something like $stud1, $stud2 and so on. I dont know how to add the value of the loop to the after the variable $stud. can you help?

Comment: sorry for late reply....but i am not getting your question..can you explain little bit more....

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays in forms

```
 <table>
    <?php while($data= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $data['Student Name']; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="StudentName[]" value="<?php echo $data['Student Name']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
   <?php }  ?>
  </table>
```

This will then pass the values of the field name as an array. You can parse it in PHP as follows :

```
   foreach ($_POST['StudentName'] as $studentInput) {
       echo 'Student name supplied is ' . $studentInput . "\n";
   }
```

Note that you can even supply an index in the html form, Assume you want to use the student id form the database.

```
<?php while($data= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="StudentName[<?php echo $data['Student Id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $data['Student Name']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
```

Your PHP code will then change to :

```
   foreach ($_POST['StudentName'] as $studentId => $studentInput) {
       echo 'Student name for id ' . $studentId . 'is ' . $studentInput . "\n";
   }
```